# why is nothing returned when I invoke .get()

Tags: python, tkinter, get, set

Having trouble setting the file path that is selected by the user and setting to variable. I am able to retrieve the path and set it to display in the entry box but I would like to capture that path and import it into another script. Maybe my logic is flawed here? What am I doing wrong?

```
    import Tkinter
    import tkFileDialog
    from Tkinter import *
    from tkFileDialog import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master



        master.title("XML Compare Tool")
        master.geometry('700x300')

        path1 = StringVar()
        path2 = StringVar()
        self.bb1 = Button(master, text="Browse", command=lambda: path1.set(askopenfilename()))
        self.bb1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


        self.bb2 = Button(master, text="Browse", command=lambda: path2.set(askopenfilename()))
        self.bb2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.confirm = Button(master, text="Confirm", command='')
        self.confirm.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='')

        self.entry1 = Entry(master, width=75, textvariable=path1)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        print path1.get()

        self.entry2 = Entry(master, width=75, textvariable=path2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.t_label = Label(master, text="Script Output")
        self.t_label.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='')

        self.t_frame = Frame(master, bg="white", height=150, width=600)
        self.t_frame.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='')
        self.t_text = Text(self.t_frame)



root = Tk()
my_gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are initializing `path1` with an empty string. So why do you think, getting that value results in anything else?

Comment: shouldn't that string be filled once the user selects the file?

Comment: do you mean `print path1.get()` ? It is executed at start before you select path.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb questions....  I'm still a beginner

Comment: I'd like to set the path that is displayed in the entry box and assign it to a variable so that it can be passed to another script. the print path1.get() was just me trying to get some kind of output

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a textvariable, you can just use `variable = entry1.get()`. A Tkinter textvariable is not like a traditional python variable, it is just used for setting the text in an entry.